# Use the Minkowski inequality to show that, for each given location $(a_i , b_i )$, $d_i(x, y) = \sqrt{(x-a_i )^2+(y-b_i)^2}$ is convex.

Tags: calculus, inequality

Use the Minkowski inequality to show that, for each given location  $(a_i , b_i )$, $d_i(x, y) = \sqrt{(x-a_i )^2+(y-b_i)^2}$ is convex.

I know the Minkowski inequality: $||f+g||_{p} \leq ||f||_{p}+||g||_{p}$
And I know convex function definition: $f(tx_1+[1-t]x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+[1-t]f(x_2)$ for every $0 \leq t \leq 1$.

What next I should do? Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: First step: Simplify the problem. Let $d\left(x,y\right) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then, $d_i\left(x,y\right) = d\left(x-a_i,y-b_i\right)$, so the function $d_i$ is obtained from $d$ by a "parallel translation" by $\left(a_i,b_i\right)$. So it suffices to prove that $d$ is convex. (Do you see why?)

Comment: yes, thanks a lot